# Interceptor not working, how to debug them

Tags: castle-windsor, castle-dynamicproxy

I'm trying to make Castle Windsor use the Interceptor I specify.

Here is my code:

```
container = new WindsorContainer();
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

container.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration
   .Types
   .FromThisAssembly()
   .BasedOn<IInterceptor>()
   .Configure(x=>x.LifestyleTransient()));               

container.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration
   .Types
   .FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
   .BasedOn<IImporter>()
   .Configure(x => x.Interceptors<LoggingInterceptor>().LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient)));

container.Register(Component
  .For<IImporterFactory>()
  .AsFactory(c => c.SelectedWith(new ImporterFactoryComponentSelector()))
  .LifeStyle.Transient);
```

After setting up Castle Windsor, I get the IImporter implementation that I need with:

```
IImporterFactory importerFactory = container.Resolve<IImporterFactory>();
var test = importerFactory.Create(FileType.M3Availability);
test.ImportFile(fileName);
```

I'm expecting for the interceptor to be called before test.ImportFile(str) is executed but it isn't

Am I doing something wrong during the components registration?

Viewing the "container" object I can see that all my object have the right interceptor (see pic)

[image: Visual Studio watch window with container object]

Am I doing something wrong during the components registration?
How can I debug this?

Comment: Is your interceptor being registered for the LoggingInterceptor service? Can you resolve that type from the container?

Answer (score 1):

Windsor can only intercept virtual methods and interfaces. In your instance you are trying to resolve concrete types and windsor can't decorate them.

The solution is to register `IImporter` with a interface and name each instance the name of the concrete implementation.

### Update

`WithServiceAllInterfaces` should register all interfaces instead of the class.

`.Named(c.Implementation.Name)` should register the interface with the name of the concrete type so you can use the name of the concrete type in your selector.

### What you need to change in your registration:

```
container.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration
    .Classes
    .FromAssemblyInThisApplication()
    .BasedOn<IImporter>()
    .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
    .Configure(c => 
        c.Interceptors<LoggingInterceptor>()
        .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient).Named(c.Implementation.Name)));
```

I tried this on your code and this works.

Comment: Hi Jakob, I've tryed your solution but it is not working.
If I mark my methods as virtual the interceptor is called. But IImporter is an interface, in fact it is the interface for all my importers (they are chosen using the IImporterFactory) so it really should work. What is the best whay to register all my importer classes? I thought using  BasedOn<IImporter>() was ok. Thanks!

Comment: Your registration is fine but your implementation is registering the concrete types, you could try instead WithServiceDefaultInterfaces if your IImporter classes only implement one interface or it is the first. Then you have to also register the name as the class name so you will resolve the interface not the concrete type.

Comment: You're correct @Jakob. The only thing I'd suggest is I'd steer away from `WithServiceFirstInterface` and instead use `WithServiceBase` or `WithServiceAllInterfaces` depending on the circumstances

Comment: Thank you @KrzysztofKozmic that seems more appropriate. I will update my answer.